# infobip api integration for 2FA in node.js

Tags: node.js, verification, totp, infobip

How to use 2FA (getting an otp during signup) using infobip in node.js? I have to use infobip during signup process by which user will get OTP and verify its mobile number.

Comment: Hey @swati, I'd really need you to give some additional pieces of information as what have you tried and what step exactly do you need help with. Regarding the sole question you put here are the documented endpoints with Node.JS examples on the right-hand side (or below endpoint description on smaller resolutions).

[2FA via SMS](https://www.infobip.com/docs/api#channels/sms/send-2fa-pin-code-over-sms) and [2FA via Voice](https://www.infobip.com/docs/api#channels/sms/send-2fa-pin-code-over-voice). To actually help you out properly tho, I really need you to add all the info to the question.

Comment: Hi, @kiselica-aldin can you help me to confirm about required things for sending SMS via infobip like API key etc which is necessary for a table if I create one? I have to use https://www.infobip.com/docs/api#channels/sms/send-sms-message this module and the first time I am going to integrate any gateway. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I can help you go through that. Do you have an account on Infobip? Without the account, you cannot have the API key. If you don't have it at all, you can create it [here](https://www.infobip.com/signup) and then you get the (limited) free account to play with (along with the API key and base URL you need)

Comment: yes, i have account on infobip and I created API key there. Now if I have to create table for all required things of infobip for sending SMS so what would be the required columns?

Comment: Aham, ok i see two things here. (1) You want 2FA via SMS (2) You (think that you) need to use [Send SMS Message](https://infobip.com/docs/api#channels/sms/send-sms-message) endpoint for it? Let's clarify on this and then I can write a proper answer with code samples hopefully.